# MC - Cordova - AppPush conflict issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilesdk, app, cordova

During the process of implementing the MC SDK with my app, there is a conflict between the 3rd Party App Push and the SDK inserted in the marketing cloud, so I'm unable to proceed further.
Our app is a hybrid app called ionic cordova, so I've used the guidelines as below link, but it is not working properly due to the collision with the existing system.
(https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin)

I've also tried to install it directly on native, but since it's a hybrid app, it's not working because of the conflict with the existing push system and the part set by ionic cordova.

I've looked into the documents provided by Salesforce, but eventhough it is the latest version; updated as of Oct 22, I can't find a way to solve this issue.
(In the documents - some pages cannot be found, and the file being downloaded and the path name to download the file are different.)

1. Are there any documents that I can refer to excluding below?

https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/testing-push/getStarted-testPushProd.html

MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v8.0.10) : 3. Add the SDK (salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io)

SFMCSdk Android : Implement the SDK in Android (salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io)

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin
(I've used 7.5 version)

2. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 8 of the SDKs is not supported in Cordova. Please see the documentation and use the 7.x SDKs as included in the plugin.

UPDATE: the plugins for both Cordova and React have been updated to support v8 of the SDK's.

Comment: I've used SDK 7.5 version

Comment: Open a support ticket.